# Delete objects in GridLayout before adding new objects

Tags: android

Every time i press a button i fill a GridLayout with several buttons. This is the code that do it, but i don't think it's necessary for you to understand my problem

```
for(int i=0; i < numeroBottoni;i++){
        Spec row = GridLayout.spec(numeroRiga, 1); 
        Spec colspan = GridLayout.spec(numeroColonna, 1);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams gridLayoutParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row,colspan);
        gridLayoutParam.width=larghezzaColonna;
        gridLayoutParam.height=larghezzaColonna;// l'altezza della colonna la faccio uguale alla larghezza
        gridLayout.addView(buttonName,gridLayoutParam);
```

}

The new buttons overlap the old ones, so i suppose i should "delete" the old buttons before adding the new ones.
But i dont know what i should do. I don't know if i have to "delete" the `button` or if i have to "clean"  the `GridLayout`.

I tried to call `invalidate()` both on `button` and  `GridLayout` but this is not the solution

Comment: Have you tried grid.removeAllViews() ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code

```
gridLayout.removeAllViews();
```

before adding the new views. Before your for loop in your code