# Clear GridLayout in Qt before using it again

Tags: qt

I'm adding 8 widgets to my gridlayout in the constructor of mainwindow.cpp then in the function of the button i am ploting in 4 new widgets which will create 4 widgets on the top of the first 8. What i want to do is to clear this gridlayout before adding the 4 widgets...

Here's my code for the constructor:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++){

    QChart *charts = new QChart();
    charts->legend()->hide();
    charts->createDefaultAxes();
    std::string name = "Channel " + std::to_string(i);
    charts->setTitle(QString::fromStdString(name));

    QChartView *chartsView_1 = new QChartView(charts);
    chartsView_1->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    if((i % 2) == 0){
        col = 0;
    }
    else{
        col = 1;
    }
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(chartsView_1,i/2,col);
    ui->gridLayout->setColumnStretch(col,1);
    ui->gridLayout->setRowStretch(i/2,1);

}
```

And here's my code for the button:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){

    QScatterSeries *series_1 = new QScatterSeries();
    for(int k = 0; k < 115; k++){
        series_1->append(pow(k,7),k);
        series_1->setMarkerSize(4.0);
    }

    QChart *charts = new QChart();
    charts->legend()->hide();
    charts->createDefaultAxes();
    charts->addSeries(series_1);
    std::string name = "Channel " + std::to_string(i);
    charts->setTitle(QString::fromStdString(name));

    QChartView *chartsView_1 = new QChartView(charts);
    chartsView_1->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    if((i % 2) == 0){
        col = 0;
    }
    else{
        col = 1;
    }

    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(chartsView_1,i/2,col);
    ui->gridLayout->setColumnStretch(col,1);
    ui->gridLayout->setRowStretch(i/2,1);


}
```

and here's the result in a pic after pressing the button

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete objects in GridLayout before adding new objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750643/delete-objects-in-gridlayout-before-adding-new-objects)

Comment: QGridLayout has no member named "removeAllViews"

Comment: try`while( gridLayout->count() ) {
QWidget* widget = gridLayout->itemAt(0)->widget();
if( widget ) {
layout->removeWidget(widget);
delete widget;
}
}`

Comment: Thank you for this, it really worked after that i made some modification:
**while( ui->gridLayout->count() ) {
        QWidget* widget = ui->gridLayout->itemAt(0)->widget();
        if( widget ) {
            ui->gridLayout->removeWidget(widget);
            delete widget;
        }
    }**