# Why is a row of Buttons added after the first round?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

The code is a mine game where there is a minefield made up out of buttons. The size and height of the minefield is set as 4 `gridsize` and 8 `gridHeight`.
The first-time initilisation works - the 4 x 8 field out of buttons pops up. But after the first game, when changing the SeekBar `minesSeekBar` the Field gets bigger by one row although `gridHeight` is not changed.
[how  it looks on the first game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mm7U.png), [how it looks after the first game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBK5q.png)

I do not quite understand how there is a  row added when `gridHeight` is never changed. I suspected that the error might be in the `start.setOnClickListener(){}` but i could not fix it as the code makes sense (to me). Everytime the field gets redone everytime you press start so it should theoratically be always the same.
i do not think the error is in `setupGame()` as the gridsize is not changed in the method.

Here is the xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="340dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
    app:cornerRadius="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="START"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<EditText
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/einsatz"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Einsatz"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sizeSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="8"
    android:progress="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridlayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
android:visibility="gone"/> 

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/minesSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="16"
    android:progress="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridlayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/start"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp" />

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp" />
```

Here the code:

public class Minen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private int gridSize = 4; // Default grid size
private int gridHeight = 8; // Default grid height
private int numMines = 2; // Default number of mines
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Button>> buttons;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> minePositions;
private boolean gameLost = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_minefield);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    Button menu = findViewById(R.id.menu1);
    GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
    SeekBar heightSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.sizeSeekBar);
    SeekBar minesSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.minesSeekBar);
    Button start = findViewById(R.id.start);
    // Set up the height seek bar listener
    heightSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
           int x = progress + 1; // Adjust for a range of 2 to 10
            setupGame();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
    minesSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            numMines = progress;
            setupGame();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    });

    // Initialize the ArrayLists for buttons and mine positions
    buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    minePositions = new ArrayList<>();

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getEinsatzFromEditText() > 0) {
                kontostandpositiv(getEinsatzFromEditText(), new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void Callbackchecked(boolean kontostandPositiv) {
                        if (kontostandPositiv) {
                            kontostandandernminus(getEinsatzFromEditText());
                            for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
                                ArrayList<Button> rowButtons = new ArrayList<>();
                                ArrayList<Boolean> rowMinePositions = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < gridHeight; j++) {
                                    Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                                    int finalI = i;
                                    int finalJ = j;
                                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            if (!gameLost) {
                                                if (minePositions.get(finalI).get(finalJ)) {
                                                    gameLost = true;
                                                    showGameOver();
                                                } else {
                                                    button.setEnabled(false);
                                                    calcwin();
                                                    checkForWin();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    rowButtons.add(button);
                                    rowMinePositions.add(false);
                                    gridLayout.addView(button);
                                }
                                buttons.add(rowButtons);
                                minePositions.add(rowMinePositions);
                            }

                            setupGame();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Minen.this, "Nicht ausreichendes Guthaben", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Minen.this, "Einsatz setzen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

and there the relevant methods:
SetupGame:

```
private void setupGame() {
    gameLost = false;

    // Reset the button states and mine positions
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridHeight; j++) {
            Button button = buttons.get(i).get(j);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            button.setText("");
            minePositions.get(i).set(j, false);
        }
    }

    // Randomly generate mine positions
    generateMinePositions();
}
```

generateMinePositions():

```
 private void generateMinePositions() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int minesPlaced = 0;

    while (minesPlaced < numMines) {
        int row = random.nextInt(4);
        int col = random.nextInt(gridHeight);

        if (!minePositions.get(row).get(col)) {
            minePositions.get(row).set(col, true);
            minesPlaced++;
        }
    }
}
```

showGameover() :

```
private void showGameOver() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Game Over! You hit a mine.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridHeight; j++) {
            if (minePositions.get(i).get(j)) {
                buttons.get(i).get(j).setText("X");
            }
            buttons.get(i).get(j).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

checkForWin():

```
private void checkForWin() {
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridHeight; j++) {
            if (!minePositions.get(i).get(j) && buttons.get(i).get(j).isEnabled()) {
                return; // Not all non-mine cells are uncovered yet
            }
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Congratulations! You win!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I dont see in your start button handler any code which would remove the previous views, so it looks like you add new ones after the previous ones.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @marcinj does that mean that a new grid is getting added everytime i press start? That means that i need to delete all buttons first hand, and then call the code in start.setonclicklistener.

Comment: tried using buttons.clear(), but it is still not working. The error says the error is now in the setupGame() method. -Out of bounds-

Comment: You should also clear your layout, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750643/delete-objects-in-gridlayout-before-adding-new-objects